# keep the list items while looping

Tags: python, list

so i want for my addition list here to save all the sum result in each cycle of the loop ::

```
def calc ():

 addition = []
 sub = []
 multi = []
 division = []
 firstNumber =float(input("Enter the first number: \n"))
 oper =input("choose the operation (+ , - , * , /) \n")
 secondNumber =float(input("Enter the second number: \n"))

 if oper == "+":
     x = firstNumber + secondNumber
     addition.append(x)
     print(x)
     print(addition)
 elif oper == "-":
        firstNumber - secondNumber
 elif oper == "*":
        firstNumber * secondNumber
 elif oper == "/":
    if secondNumber != 0:
        firstNumber / secondNumber
    else:
        print("Can't divide by zero")

while 0<1:
 calc()
 msg = input("Do you want to continue? y/n")
 if msg == "y":
    calc()
 elif msg =="n":
    break
 else:
    print("wrong choise")
```

so if my first addition result was 5 and the second was 10 ... 
the addition list be [5, 10 , ...]

Comment: You have 2 options : 1) you can add `addition` list as function argument and return it at end of function 2) make `addition` list a global variable

Comment: store `addition` in a global variable or pass it,else list is reset each time you call `calc`

Comment: thanks alot guys !

Comment: here you see the Do you want to continue? message is skipped one time ,, why ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your all your code inside the while loop except top 4 lines of your code.